# Freeman chain code in OpenCV 3

Tags: c++

In OpenCV 1 there used to be an option of cvFindContours (using CV_CHAIN_CODE) to obtain a contour from an image in Freeman chain code. However, I cannot find it in OpenCV 3. Has it been removed as option?
I know I could develop my own function to generate Freeman chain code from a contour given as a sequence of points, but I thought there was a ready-made function already available.